# Regex search & replace group in C++?

Tags: c++, regex

The best I can come up with is:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string dog = "scooby-doo";
    boost::regex pattern("(\\w+)-doo");
    boost::smatch groups;
    if (boost::regex_match(dog, groups, pattern))
        boost::replace_all(dog, string(groups[1]), "scrappy");

    cout << dog << endl;
}
```

with output:

```
scrappy-doo
```

.. is there a simpler way of doing this, that doesn't involve doing two distinct searches? Maybe with the new C++11 stuff (although I'm not sure that it's compatible with gcc atm?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) should do the trick. The provided example is pretty close to your problem, even to the point of showing how to shove the answer straight into `cout` if you want. Pasted here for posterity:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string text = "Quick brown fox";
   std::regex vowel_re("a|e|i|o|u");

   // write the results to an output iterator
   std::regex_replace(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout),
                      text.begin(), text.end(), vowel_re, "*");

   // construct a string holding the results
   std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(text, vowel_re, "[$&]") << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I see. I find this interface counter-intuitive, as you have to effectively rebuild a new string using the $x syntax to represent the regex groups in the former string. That being said, I can't think of anything better